# How to Override/Redefine Vim Search Command

Tags: vim

I need to override/redefine Vim's search operator "/" to also execute "zszH" after the search to center the search results on the screen  horizontally.

For example, I want to enter: /varchar and have the search results (i.e., the string "varchar") displayed in the middle of the scren horizontally.

I can do that now by manually entering "zszH" after each search, but that is very tedious.

Comment: There is an answer to this on the “vi and vim stack exchange” to achieve what you want: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10775/how-can-i-automatically-center-first-search-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CmdlineLeave` event. Add the following to your `vimrc`

```
augroup RecenterSearch
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineLeave [/?] call feedkeys('zszH', 't')
augroup END
```

Note: `CmdlineLeave` requires Vim 8.1

Or you can map `<cr>`:

```
cnoremap <expr> <cr> "\<cr>" . (getcmdtype() =~ '[?/]' ? "zszH" : '')
```

Some mappings which might be helpful:

```
nnoremap n nzszH
nnoremap N NzszH
```

If you do not have a new enough version on Vim then maybe look into `'wrap'` or create a mapping

For more help see:

```
:h CmdlineLeave
:h :autocmd
:h feedkeys()
:h expression-mapping
:h getcmdtype()
```